# How do string comparisons work when they contain both numbers and letters?

Tags: python, string, comparison

I'm trying to compare time in Python, and came up with some weird comparisons. I've got no idea how the following statements work:

```
>>> "17:30" > "16:30"
True
>>> "12:30" > "13:30"
False
>>> '18:00 - asdfj' > '16:30 - asdfj'
True
```

My guess is that it takes the first number from before the colon, I'm not completely sure about it.

Comment: String comparison works the same way regardless of whether it contains letters or numbers. It simply compares the two strings lexicographically, character by character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, a comparison between strings is a question of lexicographical ordering.

What that means procedurally:

- two strings are compared one character at a time
- the first character that's different decides which string is 'greater than' the other
- if no characters are different and the strings are the same length, they are 'equal'.
- if two characters are different, their 'ordinal value' decides which is 'greater'
- a character is 'greater than' no character

For example, `'ab' > 'a'` is `True`, because `'a' == 'a'`, but the first string has an extra character. And `'abc' < 'abd'` because `'c' < 'd'`.

`'a' < 'b'` because `ord('a') < ord('b')`. The ordinal value of a character is typically its ASCII value for normal characters, or more precisely, its the Unicode code point (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord). This also means that `'A' < 'a'`, because uppercase letters come before lowercase letters in Unicode. And `'1' < 'A'` because numbers come before letters.

Note that this may sometimes give surprising results (note the dots on the `Ӓ`):

```
>>> 'Ӓ' > 'a'
True
>>> 'A' > 'a'
False
```

There are many online tables and overviews of Unicode, but here's a fairly plain example: https://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html

As for your example:

```
>>> '18:00 - asdfj' > '16:30 - asdfj'
True
```

This makes sense, because `'8' > '6'` - the rest of the string doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, in python, it is [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) comparison.

Example 'a' comes before 'b', hence 'a' < 'b' is true. Similarly '2' < '3'. Hence '199' < '2' is true because 1 comes before 2.